# PHP-AES-256-ECB decrypt messy code

Tags: php, ios, encryption, cryptography, aes

```
 public function decrypt($str, $key){
    //AES, 256 ECB
    $data = rtrim(
                    mcrypt_decrypt(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                        $key, 
                        base64_decode($str), 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                        mcrypt_create_iv(
                            mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                            ), 
                            MCRYPT_RAND
                        )
                    ), "\0"
                );
   return $data;
}
```

The $str is from ios app encrypt string, he used charset is `NSUTF8StringEncoding`  and use the method `AES-256-ECB-PKCS7Padding` and base64 output.

**Before encrypt**

$str-> `42z7t5nzwvbk14gbemc9`

$key-> `gxssh2016`

**After encrypt in ios APP**

$str-> `D2k5t33l+HD3snFTU+gNYlCH/DQ37WO6I6nUYbGTDKc`

---

**notice: I used the AES online tool to decrypt this string can get the right result: `42z7t5nzwvbk14gbemc9`**

But,use my function decrypt this $str output:
`x�Z����®(t�sڞ�<�^�q�P`��`

How can I decrypt it to `42z7t5nzwvbk14gbemc9` in php?

Comment: Can you add iOS encrypt code?

Comment: <Standard comment about not using ECB that usually gets ignored anyway>

Comment: [<Standard comment about mcrypt being abandoned since 2007>](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: <Standard comment about [chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken)>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not AES256. It is a rarely used cipher (**not** part of the AES standard!) which operates similarly to AES but encrypts 256 bits (32 bytes) at a time instead of 16.

If you want to encrypt/decrypt AES256 data using mcrypt, pass a 256 bit (32 byte) key to `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`.

Better yet, though, avoid mcrypt entirely. It's a poorly written library that has been abandoned by its developer since 2007. Consider using the OpenSSL extension instead, e.g.

```
return openssl_decrypt(
    base64_decode($str),
    "aes-256-ecb",
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA
);
```

(As you've noted in your answer, your encrypted data was actually encrypted using AES128; change the "256" to "128" and this will work with your example data. I've left this code using AES256 so that it answers the question as asked.)